# I would like to do a simple code with camel, to convert a SOAP webservice to REST web service

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

I have exposed my camel project as a rest web service. http://localhost:9090/route/restservice/getQuote

How do i identify that the incoming request is SOAP or rest - if it is REST or SOAP (are there any headers to identify)

if it is SOAP how can I convert SOAP to rest in camel/routes ?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot call a REST service with SOAP and a SOAP service with REST. Question does not make sense. They are fundamentally different. If you want to expose a SOAP service and then call a rest service from that you must look at the message translator EIP. See this link http://www.eaipatterns.com/MessageTranslator.html